# Can't loop through array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that looks like this...

```html
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["data"]=>
        string(23) "football games on today"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["data"]=>
        string(8) "football"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["data"]=>
        string(14) "football today"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

etc. Normally, I would just loop through this array to get the data that I need which would look like this...

```html
$x=0;
foreach($array as $a){
 echo $a[$x][0]['@attributes']['data'].'<br>';
$x++; 
}
```

But, for some reason this very simple foreach loop will not output the data as I would expect. The loop returns nothing. I have add an

```html
$x=0;
foreach($array as $d){
 echo $d[$x][0]['@attributes']['data'].'<br>';
  echo $x.'<br>';
$x++; 
}
```

echo $x; line into the code, and it will echo the incremental x value, so I know if is looping through the array properly.

It has been a very long few days of coding, so maybe I am just burnt out and missing somethings really simple. But I am not seeing it. Thank you for any help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: `$d[$x][0]['@attributes']['data']` seems odd. Why do you have `[$x]` and later `[0]`?

Comment: Because that is the way the array is structured.

Comment: No. `$d` contains first element from `$array` meaning you only need to do `$d[0]['@attributes']['data']` to access your data. No `$x` counter is needed for `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do end up with deeply nested arrays you can gather the keys and values of the array 'leaves', by using array_walk_recursive:

```
<?php

$data = 
[
    [
        [
            'wanted' => 'foo'
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            'wanted'=> 'bar'
        ],
        'dead'=>'parrot'
    ]
];

array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$wanteds) {
    if($k==='wanted')
        $wanteds[]=$v;
});
var_export($wanteds);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
  )
```

Note the conditional check on the leaf keys to only gather the attributes wanted.

You can then loop through the generated array easily.